# Why can't I unregister multiple DLL files from the batch file?

Tags: batch-file, dll, windows-10

I have to unregister some `DLL` files and if I run the following commands directly from `cmd.exe` it works fine:

```
cd C:\Office\Client
FOR %1 IN (*.DLL) DO REGSVR32 /U /S %1
cd C:\Office\Server
FOR %1 IN (*.DLL) DO REGSVR32 /U /S %1
```

I need to run those commands from the batch file and then run the file from my code, but the problem is that the batch file immediately closes and does nothing. What may be the problem here?

Comment: You can do that in just a single line batch file: `@For %%G In ("C:\OfficeClient\*.dll" "C:\Office\Server\*.dll")Do @"%__AppDir__%regsvr32.exe" /U /S "%%~G"`.

Comment: and please do not use `%1` as a metavariable. You have an entire alphabet to use, `%1` is for std input from `cmd` as a parameter.

Comment: @Compo Didn't know that. Thanks!

Comment: @Gerhard But here `%1` works just fine for me.

Comment: @JConstantine, don't use `%1`, it is a bad habit which will eventually return to bite you. A knowledgeable member has advised you not to use it, they didn't tell you it was not working, just a reason why in some circumstances it may not.

Comment: @Compo  I also noticed that if I use that type of syntax you suggested the running commands won't show up on the screen.

Comment: That's correct, @JConstantine, because there's no point in doing so. You're already running the unregister commands with a silent option, so there's no need to see the command, if you don't want to see what it does! If you want to see each unregister command however, change it to `@For %%G In ("C:\OfficeClient\*.dll" "C:\Office\Server\*.dll")Do "%__AppDir__%regsvr32.exe" /U /S "%%~G"`.

Comment: @Compo Why do we need `@` before `For`? What does it do?

Comment: It turns `echo`ing off for the `for` command, i.e. the `for` command does not show in the cmd.exe window when it is invoked. I use that because you have clearly not shown that you have turned off `echo`ing globally, i.e. for the entire batch file, _with `@Echo Off`_.

Comment: @Compo Also what does `"%%~G"` mean?

Comment: Four months is a rather long time to have waited to ask these questions, especially given that the usage information should have given you enough of an idea. Open a Command Prompt window, type `for /?` press the `[ENTER]` key, and read the usage information.